# Fast asynchronous serial communication

Tags: c++, real-time, windows-embedded

I have a controller design application where i get data from 3 USB devices (seen as virtual com port under windows), process it, and then send the action to a 4th USB device (also virtual com port). I need to process that data once i recieve it with a minimum latency.
I decided to use C++ on windows embedded and do the serial communication using the .Net System::IO::Ports and DataReceived event. I tested my code performance using only one USB device where USB device sends one byte to the computer and then the computer sends it back. I measure the time difference and it was totally indeterministic. Sometimes 2 ms and sometime 20 ms. 
Note: the process priority is set to be realtime.

Is it a better way to get a deterministic latency where a max delay is guaranteed? may be another API suitable for realtime serial communication on windows embedded?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you cannot get a deterministic latency delay. You cannot have any guarantee. Because it is not a real-time OS.

If you want some guarantee that are mandatory for your project, you can either deport the real-time part into a smaller device like [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) (open-source, [some users made a Real Time OS with it](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=138643.0)) or a [Beck chip](http://www.beck-ipc.com/en/index.asp) (commercial, delivered with a [Real Time miniOS](http://www.beck-ipc.com/en/products/rtos/)); or you can install a [RealTime Linux](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), which brings in some guaranteed delay.